# White screen appears after splash screen - Worklight Application

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

In my Worklight application, I am getting a White Screen after my splash screen and then web page appears. I have configured the splash screen using cordova.

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

And set the properties like below

```
   <preference name="splashscreen" value="splash"/>
   <preference name="splashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
```

Note sure why the white screen appears for fraction of seconds and disappear and ten loaded my web page.

Worklight Studio Version 6.1 and Android 4.2.x

Answer (score 0):

1. What is your Worklight version?
2. What environment are you testing in?

Please **always mention** these.

Lastly, the splash screen you see in Worklight is not something you can currently control. It does not "go through" Cordova per-se.
The ability to control the duration of the splash screen (in *Android* and *iOS*) will be introduced in Worklight 6.2, [to be released in June 2014](http://www.websphereusergroup.org/go/article/view/articles/265479/impact_2014:_mobile_strategy_and_ibm_worklight_6.2).

For a list of current questions regarding the splash screen in Worklight, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D%20splash%20screen%20is:question).

Comment: Hi Idan. Thanks for the list.